# Hacer una Petición Get() con Retrofit 2 y kotlin

Tags: sql, kotlin, retrofit

Estoy estancado con una petición a una **Api Rest** en *Android*. Utilizo *Retrofit con Kotlin*. El link que debo consumir es:

https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/municipios?provincia=22&campos=id,nombre&max=100

Bueno, donde ven que tiene el número 22, ese código debe ser una **@Query** porque dependiendo de la provincia que elija el usuario, se listaran todos los municipios de esa provincia.

El problema viene cuando armo la interface, yo hice esto y no me funciona, me da un error 400.

Obviamente ya tengo preparado el Retofit con esta Base Url:

https://apis.datos.gob.ar/georef/api/

Y la interface que hice es así

```
@GET(municipios{id}&campos=id,nombre&max=100)

Suspend fun getLocalidades (@Query("provincia") id:String): Lista<Municipios>
```

*Municipios* es una data class que creé.

¿Alguien me puede guiar un poco de como hacer una petición de este tipo?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el código de tu query, ya que según lo que envías

> @GET(municipios{id}&campos=id,nombre&max=100)

Estarías formulando el query de la siguiente manera

> municipios22&campos=id,nombre&max=100

Cuando lo que deberías hacer es ejecutar el módulo municipios en el servidor (para eso se usa el caracter '?')
y pasar el id de la provincia en el campo correspondiente

> @GET(municipios?provincia{id}&campos=id,nombre&max=100)

Comment: Hector, ante todo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, voy a probar el código como me lo has marcado, yo creía que el '?' Lo agregaba automáticamente al utilizar la notación @Query. Tal vez allí esté mi error.